# Insert data into new Google sheet

Tags: java, google-sheets, google-api-java-client, google-sheets-api

I want to create empty sheet and insert some data. I tested this code:

```
Sheets service = getSheetsService();

        // Fist create empty new sheet
        List<Request> requests = new ArrayList<>();

        requests.add(new Request().setAddSheet(new AddSheetRequest()
            .setProperties(new SheetProperties()
                .setTitle("scstc"))));

        BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest body = new BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest().setRequests(requests);
        BatchUpdateSpreadsheetResponse response = service.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId, body).execute();

        // Second add data into new sheet
        List<List<Object>> writeData = new ArrayList<>();

        List<Object> dataRow = new ArrayList<>();
        dataRow.add("data 1 " + timestamp);
        dataRow.add("data 2 " + timestamp);
        dataRow.add("data 3 " + timestamp);
        dataRow.add("data 4 " + timestamp);
        dataRow.add("data 5 " + timestamp);
        writeData.add(dataRow);

        ValueRange oRange = new ValueRange();
        oRange.setRange(range); //
        oRange.setValues(writeData);

        List<ValueRange> oList = new ArrayList<>();
        oList.add(oRange);

        BatchUpdateValuesRequest oRequest = new BatchUpdateValuesRequest();
        oRequest.setValueInputOption("RAW");
        oRequest.setData(oList);

        BatchUpdateValuesResponse oResp1 = service.spreadsheets().values().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId, oRequest).execute();
```

The code is working but I have the following limitations:

The fist batch call creates empty sheet.
The second batch call inserts the test data into wrong sheet, always the fist one.

How I can create new sheet and insert data with one call? If this is not possible how I can insert data into the new sheet?

Answer (score 1):

The line `oRange.setRange(range); //` is missing the comment explaining what the line is intended to do.  You don't have any line that assigns `range` to a value, so I'm not sure what you meant it to be.

If you want to write values into your new sheet, you need to make sure that `range` is pointing to that sheet, using `range = "scstc"` (which is the title of the sheet you added).

Alternately, you can do everything in a single BatchUpdateSpreadsheet request by specifying the `sheetId` in the [`SheetProperties`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#SheetProperties) object, and then also adding an [`UpdateCellsRequest`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#UpdateCellsRequest) pointing to the same sheetId, with the `rowData`filled out as you'd like it.

Comment: For the simpler version, the fix is just to assign range to the title of your sheet -- I'm not sure what you'd want an example of.  For the more complicated (but fewer requests) version, see the [Samples](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/) in the documentation.